# Sorting a list of tuples by date in format dd month name yyyy

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a list of tuples by their date (newest to oldest).

My list is:

```
my_list = [("234","linkA" ,"FileA" , "23 March 2017"),
 ("541", "linkB", "FileB", "12 October 2019 ),
 ("9482", "linkC", "FIleC","24 February 2018")]
```

The output that I want is:

```
my_ordered_list = [("541", "linkB", "FileB", "12 October 2019 ),
 ("9482", "linkC, "FIleC","24 February 2018"),
 ("234","linkA" ,"FileA" , "23 March 2017")]
```

Tried different solutions following the answers for similar questions.

My solution is:

```
def newest_results(my_array):
my_array.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    sorted_by_oldest_date = my_array.sort(key=lambda L: datetime.strptime(L[3], '%d %B %Y'))
    return sorted_by_oldest_date
```

But it's not ordering the tuples by date. Instead, I get a `None` object instead of an ordered list

Comment: This code will order the dates in ascending order while your expected output is descending order

Comment: My mistake, I meant  descending order, however it does not provide the output I wanted. It is still not ordered neither ascending or descending.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the *correct* list? There are a lot of errors in this code that won't let it run

Comment: `my_array.sort` sorts`my_array` in place and returns `None`. You should be returning `my_array`. Of course, you should also specify `reverse=True`.

Comment: You are missing `"` in `my_list` and you have indentation errors in function `newest_result`. Your code does not run as presented.. I tried correcting this for you, but it seems you put it back the way it was.

Comment: Thanks, I understood my error. I did not know that it was sorting in place.

Answer (score 1):

Add the parameter `reverse=True` and you will get what you want:

`sorted(my_list,key=lambda L: datetime.datetime.strptime(L[3], '%d %B %Y'),reverse=True)`

Output:

```
[('541', 'linkB', 'FileB', '12 October 2019'),
 ('9482', 'linkC', 'FIleC', '24 February 2018'),
 ('234', 'linkA', 'FileA', '23 March 2017')]
```

Comment: What order are you expecting?

Comment: My mistake, I meant  descending order, however it does not provide the output I wanted. It is still not ordered neither ascending or descending. I tried both with `reverse=True` and without it but I still get a list not ordered at all.

Comment: As result of my function, I get an None object

Comment: I see your problem, you need to either call `my_ordered_list = sorted(my_list..)` or `my_list.sort(...)` and then `return my_list`, not `my_ordered_list=my_list.sort(...)` since `my_list.sort` already sort `my_list` and return `None`